# wrong results: sum of two variables

Tags: php, logic

I have a simple problem, but I can't solve it, still.

### Working code

```
(int)$sum_price=4;
(int)$price_per_sum = (int)$spo[$key]*(int)$gpp['price'];
echo $sum_price = ($sum_price + $price_per_sum);
```

When I change `4` to a variable, the result of `sum()` is string.

### Result becomes a string

```
 $spo[$key] = 1;
 $gpp['price'] = 2;
(int)$sum_price=4;
(int)$price_per_sum = (int)$spo[$key]*(int)$gpp['price'];
 echo $sum_price = ($sum_price + $price_per_sum);
```

The result is 42 but should be 6, instead. Using `(int)` does not change my result.

### Problem code

```
# Get All Payment 
(int)$sum_price = 0;
$sum_price_product = explode('|',$_SESSION['product']);
$spo = explode('|',$_SESSION['order']);
foreach($sum_price_product as $key=>$spp)
{
  if($spp!='')
  {
    $get_product_price = $dbc->select("sh_product"," id = '{$spp}'","id");
    $gpp = mysql_fetch_array($get_product_price['sql']);
    (int)$price_per_sum = $spo[$key] * $gpp['price'];
    $sum_price = $sum_price + $price_per_sum;
  echo $sum_price;
  }
}
```

http://codepad.org/Zo9X2PY5

Comment: http://3v4l.org/S7Upa

Comment: what is `$key` here? and what is constant `price` here?

Comment: If you cast prices, use `(float)` instead of `(int)` since they have decimal points too

Comment: For me, even `"4h" + "2"` outputs `6` but `"h4" + "2"` outputs `2`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Casting is not required in this case. Please review below code and try it out,its working for me:

```
$spo[0] = 1;
$gpp['price'] = 2;
$sum_price=4;
$price_per_sum = $spo[0]*$gpp['price'];
$sum_price = $sum_price + $price_per_sum;
echo $sum_price;
```

Here in $spo[0], i have considered single value but you can replace '0' by $key in loop construct.

Please review here my working code:  http://codepad.org/zH2q2WjH

Comment: can you please provide your full code with all variables value that you are using in your code?

Comment: what output are you expecting from your code that you shared on codepad.org/Zo9X2PY5 ?

Comment: sum of result numbers

Comment: Here are the issues I see: which codepad am I supposed to look at and why?  What was wrong with the logic in the initial code?

Comment: @Wolfpack: Nothing is wrong in initial code, i just removed all casting related stuff from code and it works

Comment: @KalpanaDixit What I'm saying is: why.

Answer (score 0):

Type Casting is not necessary in this case...
And please put the right associative array key its `"price"`or `'price'` not just `price`...

```
$sum_price = 4;
$price_per_sum = $spo[$key] * $gpp['price'];
$sum_price = ($sum_price + $price_per_sum);
echo $sum_price;
```

And your Example :

```
$spo[$key] = 1;
$gpp['price'] = 2;
$sum_price = 4;
$price_per_sum = $spo[$key] * $gpp['price'];
$sum_price = ($sum_price + $price_per_sum);
echo $sum_price;

# Get All Payment 
(int)$sum_price=0;
$sum_price_product = explode('|',$_SESSION['product']);
$spo = explode('|',$_SESSION['order']);
foreach($sum_price_product as $key=>$spp)
{
if($spp!='')
{
$get_product_price = $dbc->select("sh_product"," id = '{$spp}'","id");
$gpp = mysql_fetch_array($get_product_price['sql']);
(int)$price_per_sum = $spo[$key]*$gpp['price'];
$sum_price = $sum_price + $price_per_sum;
echo $sum_price;
}
}
```

Comment: I think it is a mistake, he edited the question. so this answer has no meaning anymore

Comment: @user3243573 is it working now? After edit suggestion or this answer?